# MySQL how to select on multiple tables using Not Exist

Tags: mysql, exists

I have three tables. One is a table of deletion candidates. This table was created with certain criteria, but did not include a couple of factors for consideration (limitations of the system). The other two tables were created considering those "left out" factors. So, I need to run a SELECT query on these three tables to come up with a deletion list.

What I started with is:

```
SELECT inactive.id
FROM inactive, renamed, returned
WHERE NOT EXISTS (inactive.id = remamed.id and inactive.id = returned.id)
```

But this is giving me an error. Can someone point out my error here?

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do here.

I assume you want a list of all rows from the `inactive` table that do not exist in *either* the `renamed` table or the `inactive` table. Is that right?

If so you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT inactive.id
FROM inactive
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select null from renamed where renamed.id = inactive.id)
AND NOT EXISTS (select null from returned where returned.id = inactive.id)
```

Comment: I have three tables, inactive, renamed, returned. I want a list of all rows from the inactive table that do not exist in either the renamed table or the returned table. But, from your reply, I think I see where I made two mistakes. Thank you for your help. I'll post back if regardless.

Comment: I think I should be using OR instead of AND. If I use AND, then in order for an inactive.id to be selected, it would have to not exist in both the renamed and returned tables, right? But, if I use OR, then if the inactive.id does not exist in the renamed table, will it continue and check to see if the inactive.id does not exist in the returned table?